# MySQL Group By - Get row associated with max() amount

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

What I am trying to get is the row contents containing the highest price.  I am not sure if I need to self-join, or use a having statement.  Most of the attempts I have tried netted me no returned rows.  Effectively I want to say "WHERE PRICE IS MAX".

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table

GROUP BY Store, Date, Item
```

Starting with:

```
+----+-------+-------+------+-------+
| id | Store | Date  | Item | Price |
+----+-------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | A     | 1-Jan |  123 | 0.5   |
|  2 | A     | 1-Jan |  123 | 0.75  |
|  3 | A     | 2-Jan |  456 | 0.45  |
|  4 | B     | 1-Jan |  123 | 0.85  |
|  5 | B     | 1-Jan |  123 | 0.75  |
|  6 | B     | 2-Jan |  778 | 0.45  |
+----+-------+-------+------+-------+
```

I want to end up with

```
+----+-------+-------+------+-------+
| id | Store | Date  | Item | Price |
+----+-------+-------+------+-------+
|  2 | A     | 1-Jan |  123 | 0.75  |
|  4 | B     | 1-Jan |  123 | 0.85  |
|  6 | B     | 2-Jan |  778 | 0.45  |
+----+-------+-------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is affectionately known as a groupwise max:

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: How am I able to use the three group by criteria, the examples I see are simplistic and just look for the max number.  SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);